# Reply to "See you"

Tags: word-choice

I know I can simply say `See you/Bye, etc.`, but I wonder if it sounds natural to say `You too` in response to `See you`.

Comment: i don't think so. It is natural to reply 'See you'/'See you later'. 'You too' sounds natural in response to 'have a good week-end' and similar.

Comment: You have established the "see you later" in your conversation, so there is no need to repeat it. I would just say "bye" or "later". To me "You too" sounds corny when someone says it.

Comment: I either respond to this with a simple 'ya!' or 'sure'.

Answer (score 2):

Responding to

> See you
>   See you soon
>   See you later

using

> You too *(AmE)*
>   And you *(BrE)*

would be understood. It's not usually used in that way by native speakers, but is used to respond to something like

> Have a nice day!
>   Stay cool!  *(during the summer heat)*

to mean "you also".

Comment: So, what is(are) usually used?